# "unable to resolve host error" whenever running a command with SUDO on ubuntu webserver

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I have a server on amazon which normally runs like a champ; after increasing the instance size this weekend, then decreasing it back down to its normal size, I've started to get odd errors every time I run a command under `sudo`. Here's an example:

```
sudo ps -ef
sudo: unable to resolve host domU-##-##-##-##-##-##
```

Where # is a number. Its important to note **the command then executes as expected**. I thought there might be something bound oddly in my hosts file so I had a look at that:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

And it seems pretty normal although I don't know enough to be sure. Can anyone shed some light on this repeating error and how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your hostname is in /etc/hostname. To see what is in there now, you can either run hostname -f or cat /etc/hostname.

When you move your EC2 instances around, you lose your hostname so it no longer matches the hostname at the time you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, the `/etc/hostname` file has the host in the error - so that makes sense. Can I put a generic value in there or will it need to be changed everytime I move my EC2 instance? (this has to be done weekly).

Comment: You should be able to set this automatically with a little script. Something like:

    echo 'hostname -a' > /etc/hostname

in your /etc/rc.local file should set the hostname correctly at each boot. You may have to play with the syntax a bit, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not using the correct Amazon DNS.

If your EC2 instance is in the VPC `172.31.0.0`, the DNS you should use is `172.31.0.2`. So you have to "add two" to the last number.

Only the DNS of your VPC will respond to your local hostname `ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX`.

From the documentation:

> The string AmazonProvidedDNS maps to a DNS server running on a
>   reserved IP address at the base of the VPC network range "plus two".
>   For example, the DNS Server on a 10.0.0.0/16 network is located at
>   10.0.0.2.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#AmazonDNS

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I copied settings from one availability zone to another. The DHCP Option Set for my VPC was pointing at us-west-1 but my new VPC was in us-west-2. As a result, when the machine was started, the EC2 scripts that set up the machine were putting this into my resolv.conf file

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.2
search us-west-1.compute.internal
```

After creating a new DHCP option set with domain=us-west-2.compute.internal and applying that to my VPC, once I restarted my EC2 instance, the resolve.conf file looked like this

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.2
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

(note the us-west-2 in the second block versus the us-west-1 in the first), and I no longer got the "unable to resolve host" error.